# Android Studio - MinSdkVersion on Java Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a module in my Android Studio project, which is a Java Library, in there I wrote a function like this:

```
 private boolean titleIsNotEmpty(Event event){
        return event.getTitle().trim().isEmpty();
 }
```

But on `isEmpty()` I get the following message:

> Call requires API level 9 (current min is 1) Java.lang.String#isEmpty

Also when I try to use `Function` or `Optional` classes I get the same error:

> Call requires API level 24 (current min is 1)

How can I define that on a Java Library?, my gradle build.module is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: simply the definitions of these functions and API's were added to respected versions so set your complied/target version to  24 in your case to use these functionalities

Comment: @PavneetSingh So those compatibility options do not refer to the Java Binary?

Comment: it's trade off , you want some feature you lose some backward support , many features don't have backward compatibility with v4,v7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've seen this behavior if you're using android studio and you **only** have a JAR module in the project.

Just ignore it.

Comment: So I keep working as it is and when built it is going to work fine?

Comment: just ignore it, it's some kind of bug in studio

Comment: instead of down voting, at least explain what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this add to your java module

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your current min SDK is 1...

You must look in your `build.gradle` after this line:

```
minSdkVersion **
```

You must cange the ** to your required SDK. For example 24

```
minSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim but again, that option works within the android section of the `build.gradle` file of an android module, in a Java Module I cannot add that, I've already tried it.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean.